# Errors while converting from numbers to character R

Tags: r

In R, I tried to see the summary of my data after converting them from numbers to characters and this message revealed continuously:

```
Error in nchar(x, type = "w"): invalid multibyte string, element 18
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your dataset and you've tried to do?

Comment: What are your data? What did you do? What are you expecting as result? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a system locale issue. See [this blog post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/web-scraping-and-invalid-multibyte-string) for an example that may be similar to your case use.

In a nutshell, try running this before the rest of your code:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")
```